# Adding 2 sql values into an array

Tags: php, mysql, sql, json

i am quite new to php and I want to do two select Counts on a mysql column and put these into an array. The code i have is below however this does not work.

```
// DB connection
  $link = mysqli_connect( "localhost", "username", "password", "CE_TRANSACTIONS" );

// Query users table
  $sql = "SELECT (SELECT COUNT(STATUS) FROM CE_TRANSACTIONS WHERE STATUS = 0),
  (SELECT COUNT(STATUS) FROM CE_TRANSACTIONS WHERE STATUS = 3);"

// Execute query
  $result = mysqli_query($link,$sql);

// Loop over all result rows
  $result_array = array();

     while($array = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) 
     {

        $result_array[] = $array[];
     }

// Write to JSON
   echo json_encode($result_array);
```

Hi thanks for the quick replies i am also getting the following error message
PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected T_VARIABLE for the below line.

```
  // Execute query
  $result = mysqli_query($link,$sql);
```

Comment: Some advice: when posting questions to Stack Overflow, you'll want to be more specific about behaviour than just "it does not work". You'll get better help if you can tell us specifically what you expect to happen, and what is actually happening (such as specific outputs and error messages) and why you think what is happening is wrong.

Comment: i think there is some problem with your sql query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe your problem is coming from `$array[];`

What the [] is saying is 'Access the value at', but you're not accessing any index of the array.

What you want to do is:
`$result_array[] = $array`

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
 $result_array[] = $array[];
```

to

```
 $result_array = $array;
```

You may also see performance boost by using the following query instead.

```
SELECT Sum(Case When Status = 0 Then 1 Else 0), 
       Sum(Case When Status = 3 Then 1 Else 0)
FROM   CE_TRANSACTIONS
```

Comment: Have you checked his query ..i think he is doing something wrong there..using in the csse of select statement

Comment: Yeah sorry there was a typo

Answer (score 0):

The  `PHP Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_VARIABLE` is because your line

```
$sql = "SELECT (SELECT COUNT(STATUS) FROM CE_TRANSACTIONS WHERE STATUS = 0),
  (SELECT COUNT(STATUS) FROM CE_TRANSACTIONS WHERE STATUS = 3);"
```

is missing a trailing `;`.